Error installing Ubuntu 24.04
I'm installing Ubuntu 24.04. I made a bootable USB flash drive using rufus-4.5. When booting from the flash drive I clicked install and an error pops up in the screenshot.
Windows 10 works fine on this computer.
  SMBIOS version: 3.3
  Model: B550M Pro4
  Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
  BIOS mode: UEFI
I ran a memory check with memtest86+ - no errors. The bootable USB flash drive installs normally on another device.
Error text:
[ 0.567191] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 8: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000000108
[ 0.567202] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 1ffffb0730e7e MISC d01200010000
[ 0.567213] mce: [Hardware Error]: IPID 500b0000000000 SYND 4d0000000 APIC 1 microcode 8701030
[ 0.567213] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:870f10 TIME 1725497241 SOCKET 0


That appears to be reporting a hardware error. (I thought mce was phased out in 18.04?) Are you overclocking this machine or undervolting it?  That MCE hardware event in your log happened early at boot. Do you also get MCE log entries when you use the computer normally? Try and run command line 'journalctl -k' & 'lournalctl  -p emerg..err' Also check from you BIOS any hardware debug functions available such as voltages, temperatures and fan speeds etc. If you get any more information please append it to your question. You might like to add the complete error message currently cut off.

Hello, I ran to the same problem, due to using AMD processor. Using intel processor for Ubuntu 24.04 installer based on flutter seems to be fine but not fine every time using AMD processor.
